# Possible to load one gzip file of muliple CSVs in Redshift

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load a compressed file which contain multiple CSV files into Redshift. I followed AWS documentation [Loading Compressed Data Files from Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-gzip-compressed-data-files-from-S3.html). However, I am not sure if I will be able to do following:

I have multiple CSV files for a table:

```
table1_part1.csv
table1_part2.csv
table1_part3.csv
```

I compressed these three files into one `table1.csv.gz`.

Can I load this gzip file into Redshift table using `COPY` command?

Comment: can you just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot; but using copy command you can give a folder name (containing all zip files) or wild card .. So just dont zip them into one file but independent files will work fine.

Comment: Thanks you @Deepak.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve by creating a Menifest file that should have link of all your CSV files and just specify the Menifest file in your copy command like-

```
copy customer
from 's3://mybucket/cust.manifest' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
manifest;
```

See Menifest at end.

For more details refer [Amazon Red-Shift Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html). Section "Using a Manifest to Specify Data Files".